# VS Solution Explorer - View IInterfaces before Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

Is anyone aware of any extension where you show the interfaces inside a namespace/folder at the top, ideally with a different icon, followed by the implementation classes below.

It is annoying that whenever you have a bunch of interfaces they all get shown in the middle of their current namespace as `I` is the 9th letter of the alphabet and they end up being in between of a bunch of other classes. And then if you have an actual class starting with `I`, it ends up being shoved in between a bunch of interfaces.

Is anyone ware of such an extension?

If not is anyone aware of any extension points which can be used for possibly developing a custom plugin for the built in solution explorer?

I wouldn't want to re-invent the wheel and create a brand new solution explorer :|

I use both VS2013 and VS2010. But any extension for any VS would be helpful!!

**EDIT**

Just noticed, that this is available in `Class View`, but than I lose the cascaded namespace folders  functionality :-( In class view you can sort by object type. No such thing in solution explorer?

Comment: You could put them in their own `Interfaces` folder

Comment: Yes true, but 2 problems: i have to always create an interface folder, even if a namespace has 2 interfaces, and 2 classes :|. and ReSharper complains about the namespace (yes i know im picky!). I would have to go and change the folder to not be a `Namespace Provider`.